# Cant get Angular component to work in project, using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I have created an angular componet (datetime-popup) found [here](https://github.com/Gillardo/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup)

I want to be able to use it in my projects, but i cannot get it to work.  I believe i need to make it a umd library or something with webpack, but i have had a look on this internet and i cannot find how to do this, as whatever i do, it errors.

Can someone help me to sort this out? I would like to be able to reference the project in the demo, and also use it via an external project using npm.

EDIT:

I have tried to duplicate [this project](https://github.com/jhades/angular2-library-example) but for some reason, when i build my example project, it get an exception in a script

> bundle.js:39725 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Here is the exception.  This isnt my code and works fine when the ngx-bootstrap project is in the project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging Angular libraries is still a bit of a black art. It is on the angular-cli roadmap to provide better out-of-the-box support. Meanwhile, you can consult [this excellent overview](http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/).

Basically, you need to compile your modules and components with `ngc`, based on a `tsconfig.json` with specific settings, this being a necessary step in order to create the metadata required by Angular builds, and in-line the templates and CSS (pre-processed if necessary) if they are in external files. The consuming application then imports the modules and components from the directory into which they have been compiled, often something like `dist` or `lib`, which can be accomplished with an entry in `package.json` such as `"module": "dist/index.js"`. If you are publishing to `npm`, then you could simply publish the `dist` directory. It is beyond the scope of this short answer to provide more exhaustive details.

Comment: this helped.  My demo project inside didnt work, but it works when i publish it to npm now, thanks